# Parsing JSON in for each with increment PHP

Tags: php, json, loops, parsing, foreach

I'm trying to parse a json file into a for each loop. The issue is the data is nested in containers with incremented numbers, which is an issue as I can't then just grab each value in the foreach. I've spent a while trying to find a way to get this to work and I've come up empty. Any idea?

Here is the json file tidied up so you can see what I mean - http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?url=http://ergast.com/api/f1/current/last/results.json

I am trying to get values such as [number] but I also want to get deeper values such as [Driver][code]

```
        <?php
            // get ergast json feed for next race
            $url = "http://ergast.com/api/f1/current/last/results.json";
            // store array in $nextRace
            $json = file_get_contents($url);
            $nextRace = json_decode($json, TRUE);

            $a = 0;
            // get array for next race
            // get date and figure out how many days remaining
            $nextRaceDate = $nextRace['MRData']['RaceTable']['Races']['0']['Results'][' . $a++ . '];
            foreach ($nextRaceDate['data'] as $key=>$val) {
                echo $val['number'];
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: the json doesn't really matter. you've decoded it, so it's a plain old PHP data structure, and you iterate/process it like any other PHP data structure. if you have nested structures, you need multiple nested loops.

Comment: You are using the '$a variable wrong try this: `$nextRaceDate = $nextRace['MRData']['RaceTable']['Races']['0']['Results'][$a ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While decoding the `json` there's no need to flatten the object to an Associative `array`. Just use it how it is supposed to be used.

```
$nextRace = json_decode($json);
$nextRaceDate = $nextRace->MRData->RaceTable->Races[0]->Results;

foreach($nextRaceDate as $race){
    echo 'Race number : ' . $race->number . '<br>';
    echo 'Race Points : ' . $race->points. '<br>';
    echo '===================='  . '<br>';
}
```

[**CodePad Example**](http://codepad.org/giqNo46g)

Answer (score 0):

You are nearly correct with your code, you are doing it wrong when you try the `$a++`. Remove the `$a = 0`, you won't need it.

Till here you are correct

```php
$nextRaceDate = $nextRace['MRData']['RaceTable']['Races']['0']['Results']
```

What you have to do next is this

```php
$nextRaceDate = $nextRace['MRData']['RaceTable']['Races']['0']['Results'];
foreach($nextRaceDate as $key => $value){
    foreach($value as $key2 => $value2)
        print_r($value2);
```

So, in my code, you are stopping at `Results`, and then, you want to iterate over all the results, from 0 to X, the first `foreach` will do that, you have to access `$value` for that. So, add another `foreach` to iterate over all the content that `$value` has.

There you go, I added a `print_r` to show you that you are iterating over what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you access to the elements in the nested array.
Here a way to do it:

```
$mrData = json_decode($json, true)['MRData'];

foreach($nextRace['RaceTable']['Races'] as $race) {
    // Here you have access to race's informations
    echo $race['raceName'];
    echo $race['round'];
    // ...
    foreach($race['Results'] as $result) {
        // And here to a result
        echo $result['number'];
        echo $result['position'];
        // ...
    }
}
```

I don't know where come's from your object, but, if you're sure that you'll get everytime one race, the first loop could be suppressed and use the shortcut:

```
$race = json_decode($json, true)['MRData']['RaceTable']['Races'][0];
```

Your problem is that the index must be an integer because the array is non associative. Giving a string, php was looking for the key '$a++', and not the index with the value in $a.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only the number of the first race, try this way

```
$a = 0;
$nextRaceDate = $nextRace['MRData']['RaceTable']['Races']['0']['Results'][$a];
echo "\n".$nextRaceDate['number'];
```

maybe you need to iterate in the 'Races' attribute
If you need all, try this way :

```
$nextRaceDate = $nextRace['MRData']['RaceTable']['Races'];
foreach ($nextRaceDate as $key => $val) {
    foreach ($val['Results'] as $val2) {
        echo "\nNUMBER " . $val2['number'];
    }
}
```